# How to read metadata file of disk file imaging?

Tags: python, metadata, imaging

I need one module in python that is able to read the file metadata from the ouput of disk imaging process (especially files with dd and EO1 extensions). Those file is in the context of digital evidence. This module will be work on digital preservation of evidence storage, and its logical preservation metadata schema with xml output file. Not All information of metadata should be extracted, I only need same information especially: Title, Subject, Author, Creation Time dan the most important is hash function (MD5/SHA-1).

I am working on OSX Sierra.

Comment: The `dd` tool copies disks verbatim, without any metadata. Any software that works with a block device should also work with a `dd` image.

Comment: @phihag And to add to that: DD images are raw disk images. They do not contain any metadata.

Comment: What OS? Different OS probably store different metadata. For UNIX, you can start by looking in the inode, but I doubt Title, Subject, Author are there.

Comment: Those metadata sounds like "data" to me.  If you can mount a copy of the image read-only, you can read the titles and subjects from the file content, but that would depend on the file type (is it PDF? Email? Mac OS X "Pages" document?). "Author" can mean different things (mapping to local user id? or a remote identifier?).  It's not very clear what you mean by those.  The unambiguous part is the hash, and you have the `hashlib` in Python's standard library.